# How to treat verbatim as a block that can be referenced just like a figure?

Tags: cross-referencing, verbatim

This code for example:

```
\begin{verbatim}
int main()
{
}
\end{verbatim}
```

How to add a label below it to be referenced?

```
int main()
{
}
  [code 1]
```

Comment: look for package `listings`. It can do it for you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

without option `float` there is a better spacing here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=single,caption=My caption here,label=code1]
int main()
  {
  }
\end{lstlisting}

From code~\ref{code1} it can be seen clearly....

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A workaround is to wrap it under the `figure` environment.

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{verbatim}
        int main()
        {
        }
    \end{verbatim}
    \caption{My Caption}
    \label{my-label}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: saying a code segment "Figure" looks wrong

Comment: I updated my answer to say that it's a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C,frame=single}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=My caption here,label=code1]
int main()
{
}
\end{lstlisting}

From code~\ref{code1} it can be seen clearly....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why community wiki?

Comment: @Raphink The OP already solved his problem using Herbert's comment. I just wanted to reduce the unanswered by 1. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution hack-ish but useful, largely inspired by @nikhilweee answer:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \renewcommand\tablename{Code}
    \begin{verbatim}
int main()
{
}
    \end{verbatim}
    \caption{My Caption}
    \label{my-label}
\end{table}
```

This way you have the label and caption on top and you don't have the label "Figure:" or "Table:" applied to a code block.